# How can I check if a relative URL is the current one in PHP?

Tags: php, url

I'm looking to make a PHP function that takes in a relative URL and returns whether that is this URL.

```
<?PHP
function isCurrentPage($page)
{
    //Magic
}
?>
```

this will be passed values such as `"/"`, `"/foo/bar"`, `page.php`, or even `"foo/page.php?parameter=value"`.

My first attempt involved using `$page == $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]`, but that says `"/foo/bar" != "/foo/bar/"`. That isn't much of an issue, but the difficulty comes with it saying `"/foo/bar" != "/foo/bar/index.php?parameter=value"`. For my purposes, I need it to say that these are equivalent.

**How can I tell if the current URL is one passed to this function, with the given restrictions?** I would prefer a simple, robust solution that is guaranteed to work for the next 5 years, as this is for a long-term, high-use project. Old, non-deprecated functions andor regexes are preferable.

To synopsize, the method must return `true` when on the url `http://example.com/foo/bar`:

- `isCurrentPage("http://example.com/foo/bar")`
- `isCurrentPage("http://example.com/foo/bar/")`
- `isCurrentPage("http://example.com/foo/bar/index.php")`
- `isCurrentPage("http://example.com/foo/bar/index.phps")`
- `isCurrentPage("http://example.com/foo/bar/index.phtml")`
- `isCurrentPage("/foo/bar")`
- `isCurrentPage("/foo/bar/")`
- `isCurrentPage("/foo/bar/index.php")`
- `isCurrentPage("/foo/bar?parameter=value")`
- `isCurrentPage("/foo/bar/?parameter=value")`
- `isCurrentPage("/foo/bar/index.php?parameter=value")`
- `isCurrentPage("/foo/bar/index.php#id")`
- `isCurrentPage("#id")`
- `isCurrentPage("index.php")`
- `isCurrentPage("index.php?parameter=value")`

et cetera.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: what about aliases, e.g. apache `Alias /baz /foo/bar`?

Comment: @MarcB that's not currently a concern, but I'd love to see a solution if you have one!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might be able to use the [`parse_url()` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to break apart your URL and get rid of all the non important data such as the query string.

Here is a simple example:

```
$url = 'http://yoursite.com/foo/bar?some=param';
$urlParts = parse_url($url);
// Array
// (
//     [scheme] => http
//     [host] => yoursite.com
//     [path] => /foo/bar
//     [query] => ?some=param
// )
```

You'll now be able to compare the `$urlParts['path']` against your list of known paths...

Comment: A bit incomplete, as I had to add a good couple dozen lines of code to make it work with the above listed situations, but it was the means to my solution. Thanks!

Comment: Oh...yea... With most of my answers I don't provide a copy paste solution but rather a nudge in the right direction and some useful links to relevant documentation...

Comment: I'm glad that I could help! Happy coding!

Comment: A good practice! Still, I'm having trouble when the `index.*` part of the URL is included.

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
function isCurrentPage($page)
{
      //Magic
      $page = preg_replace('/https?:\/\/[a-zA-Z0-9_\.\-]+/', '', $page);

      $url = 'http';
      if(isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') {
          $url .= 's';
      }
      $url .= '://' . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . ':' . $_SERVER['SERVER_PORT']  . $page;
      $handle = curl_init($url);
      curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

      /* Get the HTML or whatever is linked in $url. */
      $response = curl_exec($handle);

      /* Check for 404 (file not found). */
      $httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
      curl_close($handle);

      return $httpCode != 404;
}
```

Comment: This breaks when `$page` is `"https://example.com/foo"`, as the first line makes `$url` `"http://example.com:80https://example.com/foo"`. +1 for error checking, though!

Comment: the problem still stands, except now it makes `$url` `"https://example.com:80https://example.com/foo"`

Comment: Awesome, works well. Unfortunately, @Lix's solution is more elegant and probably more futureproof, and it's the one I ended up using. Thanks for your answer, though! I really like the use of regexes and error checking

Comment: Doesn't support non-ASCII characters in the URL. It may have been a solution back in the '90s...

Comment: @Alph.Dev Are you sure? It looks like the only codepoint limit is the domain name, which is still ASCII-only. Even the fancy new Chinese and Russian TLDs are really ASCII under the hood (e.g. [`.рф` is really `.xn--p1ai`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/.%D1%80%D1%84)).

Comment: @Supuhstar Yes, sure. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d306f55d6ef28755c815e4bbd28c59fed5716277 Regex selector `a-z` matches only letters from latin alphabet.

Comment: @Alph.Dev correct... but the domain name you use as an example, `моя.страница.ру`, is actually `http://xn--l1ae5c.xn--80aaxtnfh0b.xn--p1ag/`. So, what you'd really regex against is: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/bed8484b311f6c72e69b2ac89b66ff39538933d6

Comment: @Supuhstar What do you mean by "it's actually.."? Have you tested or read the docs stating whether `$_SERVER[...]` variables will contain that notation? Anyway, I can agree that this regex will work if you *ensure* (with additional code or not) that variables in the function use ASCII notation of multi-byte characters before applying regex.

Comment: @Alph.Dev by "actually", I mean what the nameservers (and ISPs?) interpret and store in their database. To this day, a domain name of any given level can only match `/[a-z0-9-]+/`, so they have to do some fanciness with the name to encode international ones. Read more: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalized_domain_name